# How do I disable verification of the SSL Certificate while using PySocks and Socks5 Proxy?

Tags: python, ssl, urllib2

This seems to get me close:
[SOCKS5 proxy using urllib2 and PySocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597485/socks5-proxy-using-urllib2-and-pysocks)
But it seems that if I try to add the context to disable the SSL verification it just ignores it.
I am not the greatest at python, but it looks like the inheritance of the class in PySocks takes the same things as HTTPShandler.
https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks/blob/master/sockshandler.py
If so I thought I could just pass the context=context in without and issue.
But it doesn't work.
Here is my method...

```
def make_http_call(url, socks_hostname=None, socks_port=None, socks_username=None, socks_password=None, params=None):
    """
    Make a HTTP GET request to given url.
    """
    import ssl
    url = add_url_params(url, params)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    context = ssl._create_unverified_context
   if socks_hostname and socks_port and socks_username and socks_password:
        # Use proxy instead if params are provided
        print "Socks Proxy is being used..."
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(
            SocksiPyHandler(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, socks_hostname, socks_port, True, socks_username, socks_password, context=context))
    else:
        print "Socks Proxy not in use..."
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = opener.open(request).read()
    return response
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

For the context variable i would do this(untested code):

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.verify_mode = CERT_NONE
context.check_hostname = False
```

The last line is not necessary as we are not checking the certificate, but it is just in case. Now i do not recommend this as this will not ensure that you are communicating with who you think you are and i do not recommend using any python version below 3 because they are known to have big security issues, [See Here](https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/the-not-so-sorry-state-of-ssl-in-python/).